# A question about inverses on nonassociative binary operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $(S,*)$ is a nonassociative binary operation, with an identity $e$. Suppose that $x$ commutes with $y$ under $*$, and $x'$ and $y'$ are two-sided inverses of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Note that, since $*$ is nonassociative, there could be more than one two-sided inverse. Does $x'$ and $y'$ commute as well? Basically, if $x$ and $y$ commute, does every two-sided inverse of $x$ commute with every two-sided inverse of $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to construct an example with $x=y$, so we have two non commuting
two-sided inverses of $x$, $a$ and $b$ say. How about this table for the
operation?
$$\matrix{e&x&a&b\\x&e&e&e\\a&e&e&a\\b&e&b&e}$$